# Why I am getting an error when trying to create an audience?

Tags: firebase, creation, server-error, audience

Whenever I try to create a new Audience for my ios app on Firebase I get the error : " Cannot be created due to a server error". No matter the parameters I include.

A week ago it was working correctly,I have tested from other computers on the same project.

I only have one project, so I Cannot test on other projects.

Thanks lots

Comment: Same here for our project. I'll file a ticket and come back once answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with audience creation is a known bug.
The engineers are already looking for possible solutions to fix it.

*Update*: Got an e-mail this morning that it should be fixed now. Checked it and it's working again for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just checked and looks as already fixed. Seems to be working correctly.